# Using values of a variable with Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I'm trying to learn and understand variables use in `Bash`. Either I am looking wrong or I'm getting the concept wrong, because I see everywhere how to initialize variables, but I do not see explained how to use that value.

Example: I have a variable called `FILES`, which gives me X number of strings that I have to look for if they exist. Something like this:

```
FILES="inf.txt program.c"
```

That just has 2, and I would have to look 1 by 1 if the files exist (the .txt and the .c ones, they are examples at random, could be more).

Now, my problem is I don't know to... assign each of the strings, or each of the values, to a new order. If it just were 1 string, I guess I could look for it, but being several I have no idea how is that done in bash.

And I kind of know how to check if a file exist, with `[-r File]` or `-e` or what not, but I do not have the value of said variable.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this in `bash` is to use an array, not a string. What if you have a file whose name contains a space?

```
$ FILES=( "name with    space.txt" inf.txt program.c )
$ for f in "${FILES[@]}"; do
>    echo "$f"
> done
```

I put a ridiculous number of spaces in the first file to emphasize the importance of quoting `$f` in the body of the loop. Try running the same code but with `echo $f` (no quotes) instead.

At this point, they are just strings. `bash` doesn't care if they are file names unless you use them in a context where file names are expected, such as with the `-f` operator (is the argument a file?):

```
$ FILES=( "name with    space.txt" inf.txt program.c )
$ for f in "${FILES[@]}"; do
>    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
>        echo "$f is a file"
>    else
>        echo "$f is not a file"
>    fi
> done
```

But since this is `bash`, not `sh`, you should use a conditional expression instead of the `test`/`[` command:

```
>    if [[ -f $f ]]; then
```

With that expression, you can remove the quotes if you like; they are all but mandatory with `[...]` (by which I mean, the code will execute without quotes, but only if `$f` contains no whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through $FILE variable with `for` loop:

```
for file in $FILES
do
[ -r "$file" ] && echo File $file exists and is readable || echo F*emphasized text*ile $file does not exists
done
```

Comment: Thing is, how does  that loop that each part of the variable $FILES is a file? Is that implicit somehow?

For me, each part of $FILES is a String, but maybe I'm mixing things up.

Comment: Now, of course it is a string; but when you use this string with a operation that implies files, the string is interpreted as a filename (for example `test -r` intetprets a string as a filename).

Comment: Mmm ok thanks that's very interesting... the operation itself is somehow simple, problem is/was understanding what is going on.

If the variable $FILE were a date or another type, and I did an operation that would compare dates, or that would compare ints, the principle behind it would be the same right?

Comment: Yes, of course. All variables have in shell type string (it is possible to have type integer also, but that is rare) but the will be treated depending on command you run.